# How do I change my cursor to a hand ONLY when it is hovering over a Label?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def changeCursor(event, pointerName):
    root.cursor(pointerName)
link = Label(root, text="Link")
link.bind("<Motion>", lambda event : changeCursor(event, "hand"))
link.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I want my cursor to change into a "hand" when my cursor is hovering over it. I also want to change my cursor back into an arrow when the cursor leaves the area occupied by the label. However I get the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Arnob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 137, in main
    seq, request = rpc.request_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.05)
  File "C:\Users\Arnob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\queue.py", line 172, in get
   raise Empty
queue.Empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Arnob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 2, in changePointer
  File "C:\Users\Arnob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2095, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'cursor'
```

How do I change the cursor into a hand when it is in the area occupied by the Label and then change it back to an arrow when it leaves the area occupied by the Label?

Comment: I think all you need is `link = Label(root, text="Link", cursor="hand2")`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want the cursor to always be the hand, just configure the label to have that cursor:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text="Hello, world", background="bisque", cursor="hand1")
label.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: where I can found full value list for cursor

Comment: @ABHIJIT https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/cursors.html

Answer (score 7):

```
import tkinter as tk    
root = tk.Tk()    
myLabel= tk.Label(root, text="Click Me", cursor="hand2")
myLabel.pack()    
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

For a quick preview of the available cursors:

(taken from https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/cursors.htm)

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

cursors = """
X_cursor
arrow
based_arrow_down
based_arrow_up
boat
bogosity
bottom_left_corner
bottom_right_corner
bottom_side
bottom_tee
box_spiral
center_ptr
circle
clock
coffee_mug
cross
cross_reverse
crosshair
diamond_cross
dot
dotbox
double_arrow
draft_large
draft_small
draped_box
exchange
fleur
gobbler
gumby
hand1
hand2
heart
icon
iron_cross
left_ptr
left_side
left_tee
leftbutton
ll_angle
lr_angle
man
middlebutton
mouse
pencil
pirate
plus
question_arrow
right_ptr
right_side
right_tee
rightbutton
rtl_logo
sailboat
sb_down_arrow
sb_h_double_arrow
sb_left_arrow
sb_right_arrow
sb_up_arrow
sb_v_double_arrow
shuttle
sizing
spider
spraycan
star
target
tcross
top_left_arrow
top_left_corner
top_right_corner
top_side
top_tee
trek
ul_angle
umbrella
ur_angle
watch
xterm""".split()

i = 0
j = 0
for cur in cursors:
    if i == 20:
        i = 0
        j += 1
    tk.Button(frame, text=cur, height=2, width=15, cursor=cur).grid(row=i, column=j)
    i += 1

tk.mainloop()
```