# How to show a Hand Cursor inside Text Widget when the User puts the mouse cursor over the Link

Tags: python, tkinter

I want the code to show a hand cursor when i hover the link, but i don't know where to insert "cursor = 'hand2'" in the code. Can anyone help me with it?

```
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser

root = Tk()

text2 = Text(root, height = 20, width = 50)
text2.tag_configure("config1", font = ("Verdana", 20, "bold"))
text2.tag_configure("config2", foreground = "#476042", font = ("Tempus Sans ITC", 12, "bold"))
text2.insert(END,"\nWilliam Shakespeare\n", "config1")
quote = """
To be, or not to be that is the question:
Whether 'tis Nobler in the mind to suffer
The Slings and Arrows of outrageous Fortune,
Or to take Arms against a Sea of troubles.
"""
text2.insert(END, quote, "config2")

text2.tag_configure("link", foreground = "blue", font = ("Georgia", 10, "bold"))
text2.tag_bind("link", "<1>", lambda e: webbrowser.open_new("http://www.ecosia.org"))
text2.insert(END, "(LINK)", "link")

text2.pack(side = "left")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change my cursor to a hand ONLY when it is hovering over a Label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45184462/how-do-i-change-my-cursor-to-a-hand-only-when-it-is-hovering-over-a-label)

Comment: My question was related with "pure" inserted text inside a Text Widget. I didn't used Label Widgets. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **tag_bind** method allows you to add event bindings to text having a particular tag. Tags can generate mouse and keyboard events, plus Enter and Leave events.

your code should looks like:

```
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser

root = Tk()

text2 = Text(root, height = 20, width = 50 )
text2.tag_configure("config1", font = ("Verdana", 20, "bold"))
text2.tag_configure("config2", foreground = "#476042", font = ("Tempus Sans ITC", 12, "bold"))
text2.insert(END,"\nWilliam Shakespeare\n", "config1")
quote = """
To be, or not to be that is the question:
Whether 'tis Nobler in the mind to suffer
The Slings and Arrows of outrageous Fortune,
Or to take Arms against a Sea of troubles.
"""
text2.insert(END, quote, "config2")


def show_hand_cursor(a):
    text2.config(cursor="hand2")
def hide_hand_cursor(a):
    text2.config(cursor='')


text2.tag_config("link", foreground="blue", underline=1)
text2.tag_bind("link", "<Enter>", show_hand_cursor)
text2.tag_bind("link", "<Leave>", hide_hand_cursor)


text2.tag_configure("link", foreground = "blue", font = ("Georgia", 10, "bold"))
text2.tag_bind("link", "<1>", lambda e: webbrowser.open_new("http://www.ecosia.org"))
text2.insert(INSERT, "(LINK)", "link")


text2.pack(side = "left")

root.mainloop()
```